Google Document AI API Returning Worse Results Than Console
I am trying to use the google document ai api.
I have created a custom processor and defined a custom schema. When I upload a document through the console, the processor highlights almost all of the fields necessary, without any additional training or labeling required.
However, when I send my document to the API using the google java client library in kotlin, only a handful of fields are extracted.
Can someone help me understand why the performance of the API is worse than what I see in the console?
I am using the java client library in Kotlin. THis is how I am sending my request:
This is how I send my request:
`val settings = DocumentProcessorServiceSettings
.newBuilder()
.setEndpoint(endpoint)
.build()
DocumentProcessorServiceClient.create(settings).use { client ->
  // The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
  // projects/project-id/locations/location/processor/processor-id
  // You must create new processors in the Cloud Console first
  val name = String.format(
    "projects/%s/locations/%s/processors/%s",
    projectId,
    location,
    processorId
  )

  // Read the file.
  val fileData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath))

  // Convert the image data to a Buffer and base64 encode it.
  val content = ByteString.copyFrom(fileData)

  val document = RawDocument
    .newBuilder()
    .setContent(content)
    .setMimeType("application/pdf")
    .build()

  // Configure the process request.
  val request = ProcessRequest
    .newBuilder()
    .setName(name)
    .setRawDocument(document)
    .build()

  // Recognizes text entities in the PDF document
  val result = client.processDocument(request)
  val documentResponse = result.document
  println("${documentResponse.entitiesList}")
  documentResponse.entitiesList.forEach { entity ->
    println("Entity type: ${entity.type}")
  }`


Hi @Dhruv Luthra, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
